# Remover elementos duplicados de uma lista encadeada em python

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, funções, lista-encadeada

Meu código retorna erro ao tentar rodar:

```
class No:
    def __init__(self,inidado):
        self.dado = inidado
        self.proximo = None

    def pegaDado(self):
        return self.dado

    def pegaProximo(self):
        return self.proximo

    def botaDado(self,novoDado):
        self.dado = novoDado

    def botaProximo(self,novoProximo):
        self.proximo = novoProximo

class ListaNaoOrdenada:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.inicio = None

    def Inserir(self,item):
        temp = No(item)
        temp.botaProximo(self.inicio)
        self.inicio = temp

    def Imprimir (self):
        atual = self.inicio
        while atual != None:
            print (atual.pegaDado())
            atual = atual.pegaProximo()

    def removeDuplicados(self):
        atual = segundo = self.inicio
        while atual != None:
            while segundo.pegaProximo != None:  
                if segundo.pegaProximo.pegaDado == atual.pegaDado:
                    segundo.pegaProximo = segundo.pegaProximo.pegaProximo  
                else:
                    segundo = segundo.pegaProximo

                atual = segundo = atual.pegaProximo
l = ListaNaoOrdenada()
l.Inserir(2)
l.Inserir(5)
l.Inserir(5)
l.Inserir(5)
l.Imprimir()
l.removeDuplicados()
l.Imprimir()
```

Gostaria de saber o que mudar para retornar apenas 2

Comment: E qual é a mensagem de erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Não estou debugando o erro no seu código mas o python tem um data type nativo
que é parecido com uma lista não ordenada, e remove duplicatas por definição:
`set` (conjunto em português).

Exemplo:

```
>>> myset = set()
>>> myset.add(1)
>>> myset.add(5)
>>> myset.add(5)
>>> myset.add(5)
>>> print(myset)
{1, 5}
```

E claro, você pode facilmente tranformá-lo em uma lista ou em uma lista
ordenada:

```
# Tranforma em lista.
>>> print(list(myset))
[1, 5]
>>> myset.add(-10)
>>> print(sorted(myset))
[-10, 1, 5]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!
A principal dificuldade era em debugar o código dentro da class de ListaNaoOrdenada, mas com essa função set ajudou muito. Grato!

Comment: @MrPamonha, se você gostou da solução você pode "aceitar" ela (para aparecer um tick verde de "ok" na resposta). Obrigado : )